# mapview random annotation image

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm having great trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong here...
I am adding annotations to my mapview through loops, but the annotation image is completely random every time... when I `NSLog` the order, it's random - i'm not sure if that is the problem.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    if ([[annotation subtitle] isEqual:@"Bar"]) {

        MKAnnotationView *view = nil;

        view = [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"myAnnotationIdentifier"];
        if (!view) {
            // Could not reuse a view ...

            // Creating a new annotation view
            view = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"myAnnotationIdentifier"];


            view.enabled = YES;
            view.canShowCallout = YES;
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"beer.png"];
        }

        return view;
    }
    else if ([[annotation subtitle] isEqual:@"Club"]) {

        MKAnnotationView *view = nil;

        view = [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"myAnnotationIdentifier"];
        if (!view) {
            // Could not reuse a view ...

            // Creating a new annotation view
            view = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"myAnnotationIdentifier"];


            view.enabled = YES;
            view.canShowCallout = YES;
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clubs.png"];
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

the view.image is totally random... either `clubs.png` or `beer.png`.. 
How do I make it correctly?

this is how I add the annotations:

```
- (void)barLoop {

    for (int i = 0; i<barArray.count; i++) {

        int index = [[barArray objectAtIndex:i]intValue];

        NSString *lati = [[[self.usersLocationArray objectAtIndex:index]
                           valueForKeyPath:@"items.Latitude"]componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        NSString *longi = [[[self.usersLocationArray objectAtIndex:index]
                            valueForKeyPath:@"items.Longitude"]componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        NSString *barNavn = [[[self.usersLocationArray objectAtIndex:index] valueForKeyPath:@"items.Navn"]componentsJoinedByString:@""];


        float latitude = [lati floatValue];
        float longitude = [longi floatValue];

        MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0} , {0.0, 0.0} };
        region.center.latitude = latitude;
        region.center.longitude = longitude;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.20f;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.20f;
        [mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
        location.latitude = latitude;
        location.longitude = longitude;
        Annotation *ann = [[Annotation alloc]initWithPosition:location];
        ann.title = barNavn;
        ann.subtitle = @"Bar";
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:ann];
    }
}
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two types of annotations, but you are only setting the image when the annotation is originally created. Thus, if an annotation for a bar scrolls off the map view and another annotation for a club scrolls on, it might reuse the bar's annotation view for the club.

There are two ways of fixing this:

1. Use different `reuseIdentifier` parameters for each of the two types of annotation views; or
2. Set/reset the annotation view's `image` regardless of whether your call to `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier` succeeded in returning a value or not.

---

Unrelated, but your `viewForAnnotation` method should:

1. You might want to use `isEqualToString` instead of `isEqual` when checking for `@"Bar"` vs `@"Club"`.
2. Make sure to return `nil` if neither of those `if` clauses return true (this should never happen, but nonetheless you have a potential path in this routine in which you neglect to return any value). I would guess that this would have been brought to your attention if you ran the code through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on Xcode's "Product" menu).
3. A more subtle observation, but I'd probably not rely upon the annotation's `subtitle` for determining which annotation view to employ, but rather either

   - have two annotation subclasses, one for bars and one for clubs; or
   - have a custom property in your existing `Annotation` class that indicates whether it's a bar or club (and I'd probably use an `enum` for that).

   At some future date, you might want to use the callout's subtitle for something other than "Bar" vs "Club" (e.g., maybe the address of the bar/club?), and the current model seems to conflate a UI attribute (i.e. what shows up in the callout) with a state property (i.e. a variable that controls which annotation view type to use). Not a big deal, but just an suggestion.

Comment: thanks so much Rob!! using a different reuseIdentifier solved my problem :) I'm going to try my luck with the suggestion of determining wheter it's a club or bar - it makes sense to have the address of the bar/club. thanks so much rob!